# rtl_sdr: reliably detect frequency changes, discard samples obtained prior

Tags: c, race-condition

I am writing a seek routine for analog FM radio using rtl_sdr with a generic DVB-T stick (tuner is a FC0013). Code is mostly taken from `rtl_power.c` and `rtl_fm.c`.

My approach is:

- Tune to the new frequency
- Gather a few samples
- Measure RSSI and store it
- Do the same for the next frequency
- Upon detecting a local peak which is above a certain threshold, tune to the frequency at which it was detected.

The issue is that I can’t reliably map samples to the frequency at which they were gathered. Here’s the relevant (pseudo) code snippet:

```
/* freq is the new target frequency */
rtlsdr_cancel_async(dongle.dev);
optimal_settings(freq, demod.rate_in);
fprintf(stderr, "\nSeek: currently at %d Hz (optimized to %d).\n", freq, dongle.freq);
rtlsdr_set_center_freq(dongle.dev, dongle.freq);

/* get two bursts of samples to measure RSSI */
if (rtlsdr_read_sync(dongle.dev, samples, samplesSize, &samplesRead) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "\nSeek: rtlsdr_read_sync failed\n");
/* rssi = getRssiFromSamples(samples, samplesRead) */
fprintf(stderr, "\nSeek: rssi=%.2f", rssi);

if (rtlsdr_read_sync(dongle.dev, samples, samplesSize, &samplesRead) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "\nSeek: rtlsdr_read_sync failed\n");
/* rssi = getRssiFromSamples(samples, samplesRead) */
fprintf(stderr, "\nSeek: rssi=%.2f\n", rssi);
```

When I scan the FM band with that snippet of code, I see that the two RSSI measurements typically differ significantly. In particular, the first measurement is usually in the neighborhood of the second measurement taken from the previous frequency, indicating that some of the samples were taken while still tuned into the old frequency.

I’ve also tried inserting a call to `rtlsdr_reset_buffer()` before gathering the samples, in an effort to flush any samples still stuck in the pipe, with no noticeable effect. Even a combination of

```
usleep(500000);
rtlsdr_cancel_async(dongle.dev);
rtlsdr_reset_buffer(dongle.dev)
```

does not change the picture, other than the `usleep()` slowing down the seek operation considerably. (Buffer size is 16384 samples, at a sample rate of 2 million, thus the `usleep()` delay is well above the time it takes to get one burst of samples.)

How can I ensure the samples I take were obtained **after** tuning into the new frequency?

- Are there any buffers for samples which I would need to flush after tuning into a different frequency?
- Can I rely on tuning being completed by the time `rtlsdr_set_center_freq()` returns, or does the tuner need some time to stabilize after that? In the latter case, how can I reliably tell when the frequency change is complete?
- Anything else I might have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the code of `rtl_power.c` again, I found this function:

```
void retune(rtlsdr_dev_t *d, int freq)
{
    uint8_t dump[BUFFER_DUMP];
    int n_read;
    rtlsdr_set_center_freq(d, (uint32_t)freq);
    /* wait for settling and flush buffer */
    usleep(5000);
    rtlsdr_read_sync(d, &dump, BUFFER_DUMP, &n_read);
    if (n_read != BUFFER_DUMP) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: bad retune.\n");}
}
```

Essentially, the tuner needs to settle, with no apparent indicator of when this process is complete.

`rtl_power.c` solves this by waiting for 5 milliseconds, then discarding a few samples (`BUFFER_DUMP` is defined as 4096, at sample rates between 1–2.8M).

I found 4096 samples to be insufficient, so I went for the maximum of 16384. Results look a lot more stable this way, though even this does not always seem sufficient for the tuner to stabilize.

For a band scan, an alternative approach would be to have a loop acquiring samples and determining their RSSI until RSSI values begin to stabilize, i.e. changes are no longer monotonic or below a certain threshold.